# Force RecordTypeId to Null on Contact

Tags: data-loader, record-type, update, upsert, null

I am working in a very old org where majority of the contacts do not have a recordtypeid, and contact visibility, page layout assignments revolve around this master no record type id contact record.

A process incorrectly created a series of contacts with a recordtypeid assigned and to align them with the rest of the org, we are attempting to remove the recordtypeid.

However we are unable to do this. Data loader and dev console although they take the update, the update does not reflect a removed recordtypeid, the populated record type id persists.

Is it not possible to set a recordtype id to null after one has been set?

Answer (score 2):

You can only set the Master Record Type (a null record type) if your profile has **no** record types assigned to it. Once you've set your profile correctly, you can do this via execute anonymous or Data Loader (or any other tool). Note that the Data Loader requires the "set null values" option to be enabled in order to set a null value to any field. You should also be able to use the null Record Type Id `000000000000000AAA`, which is internally how a null reference is stored.

Comment: My org is returning when using the null record type id you provided: "[object Object]: An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support:". I verified the System Admin profile has no record types assigned to it (--Master-- is assigned) and data loader has the "Insert Null values" setting enabled. The same setting is returned whether I'm in the dev console and hitting the save rows button or if I'm in Data Loader. This happens for Update and Upsert operations.

Comment: When using no value for RecordTypeId in dev console or data loader, salesforce states it successfully updates, but re-querying the record shows the recordtypeid did not update to null.

Comment: I am seeing the same as above - sending null or '' via anonymous apex or data load does not remove the record type, and setting recordTypeId to the 000... null id throws an exception.  Will log a case

Comment: Deactivating and deleting the record type per the suggestion [on this post](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000Gdg2RUAR/update-recordtype-to-master-on-an-existing-record) was successful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Salesforce inspector plugin .. it is simple and uncomplicated .. behind it it uses the data loader and you can make changes by importing and exporting the data to excel.
In an easy way.

If you want to know how to use access the link [enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GBEWve5NecU)
or [enter link description here](https://www.mstsolutions.com/technical/salesforce-inspector/)

About your solution .. it would help to pass the values ​​to a certain recordType.